# SSRS Expression to Split and Return Every Field in Comma Separated String

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have a string being passed into SSRS in the format `ID::Description,ID2::Description2`. This can extend to any number of strings separated by a comma. I need to be able to:

1. Split strings to only show `Description`
2. Return all of the possible `Descriptions`, no matter how many there are. I know the SSRS function `Split` can split on the comma and return with `.GetValue(<index>)`, but I need to be able to return all indexes with an indeterminate amount of possible strings.

Stipulation: I cannot modify the data on the database end, this must be done through an expression inside SSRS.

SSRS Version: 13.0.5820.21

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this with a function.

```
Function FormatDocs(str as String) as String
     Dim rtn as String = ""
     Dim strElements = str.Split(",")
     For i as Integer = 0 to UBound(strElements)
          rtn = rtn + ParseCode(strElements(i), "D")
          If i <> UBound(strElements) Then
               rtn = rtn + ", "
          End If
     Next
     Return rtn
End Function
```

`ParseCode` was an existing function we had that splits a single `ID::Description` string on `::` and returns the `Description`.

The definition for that function is as follows:

```
Function ParseCode(codeValue As String, returnType As String) As String
    Dim rtn As String = "" 
    If Len(codeValue)  Then
       Dim codeElements = codeValue.Split(":")
       If returnType  = "C"  Then 
         rtn =codeElements(0) 
       Else
         rtn =rtn +  codeElements(2)  
       End If 
    End If
    Return rtn
End Function
```